# Pug: compilation of extended blocks in a condition

Tags: compilation, pug

I recently moved from Jade to Pug and I encountered a problem compiling my code. The code of a block inserted in a condition is no longer called, only the alternate message (`[content]`) is returned :

```
// PatternLayouts.pug
block var
  //- Default values
  // [etc...]
  - contentlarge = false
main(itemprop='mainContentOfPage')
  if contentlarge
    block content
      // Default
      p [Content]
  else
    .section
      .wrap
        h1(itemprop='headline name').emphasized= name
        block content
          // Default
          p [Content]
```

If variable `contentlarge = false` then no interpretation problem, but if this is equal to true the code defined by the alternative condition (`else`) does not work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found, it is actually a regression of functionality: [Github, issue # 2367](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2367)